# Implementing OpenLayers3 basemap from tiles created using gdal2tiles

Tags: openlayers, tiles, gdal2tiles, generate-tiles

I recenty discovered the gdal2tiles.py tool which is working great with OpenLayers 2.x, but I wanted to use the new release of OL and I'm having some troubles. I have googled for a solution but i did not found a way to go.
Here is my code, inspired from the solutions offered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/TMS/ol3-dev/JLn0lfHvI7w/q7C3O8_b0-UJ (still referring to the dev version of OL3, different it seems to the release).

```
var tileUrlFunction = function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
  if (!tileCoord) { return ""; }

  var x = tileCoord[1];
  var y = tileCoord[2];
  var z = tileCoord[0];

  if (x < 0 || y < 0) { return "";}

  return 'http://localhost/map-tiles/'+ z.toString()+'/'+ x.toString() +'/'+y.toString() +'.png';
}

var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      tileUrlFunction: tileUrlFunction
    })
  })
];

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: layers,
  renderer: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [2900,-3900],
    zoom: 3
  })
});
```

I've tried several combinations of the `x`, `y` and `z` assignment without success. Tiles on the browser are completely wrong and or missing.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue or find a way to load tiles locally ?

Comment: No @Alophind, I opted for OpenLayer 2.x in my project...

Comment: Your code seems correct. What you can do is to check in the Firefox/Chrome developer tools which URLs is the page trying to download. Maybe the coordinates are not what you would expect, or you need to calculate a modulo.

Answer (score 6):

The main point is that by default OpenLayers 3 follows the widely-used Google grid where `x` 0 and `y` 0 are in the top left. Grids like TMS where `x` 0 and `y` 0 are in the bottom left can be used by using the `{-y}` placeholder in the URL template, and `tileUrlFunction` is only necessary when really a custom tile grid is utilized.

When using `gdal2tiles`, the following should work:

```
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      url: 'http://localhost/map-tiles/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
    })
  })
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this in a different way. I used this post http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/Geospatial/gdal2tilesTMSStructure.aspx to create TMS tiles and than using ol.source.XYZ to display them.